# Android: ObjectInputStream throws ClassCastException when reading arraylist

Tags: android, arraylist, classcastexception, objectinputstream

I have an arraylist of a certain POJO object that implements serializable. When I write the object to disk I do it like so:

```
File outputDir = context.getCacheDir();
File outputFile = new File(outputDir,  getCacheKey() );
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outputFile)));
oos.writeObject(arraylistOfMyObjects);
oos.close();
```

and when I later want to read back this list into an arraylist of the object, I do it like so:

```
File outputDir = context.getCacheDir();
File outputFile = new File(outputDir,  getCacheKey() );
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(outputFile)));
final ArrayList<myObject> list = (ArrayList<myObject>) ois.readObject();
ois.close();
```

I'm receiving frequent exceptions on the line where I cast the inputstream to an arraylist, with the error looking like this:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.io.ObjectStreamClass
```

Why are these errors occurring and how can I change my code to resolve them?

Interestingly enough the error doesn't occur every time I run the app, but only every now and again for whatever weird reason.

Comment: myObject is made up almost entirely of basic types (ints, Strings, etc.), but what few objects it has all implement serializable also. I've double checked

Comment: If I were in your shoes I would try two different cases:
1. try to change myObject to basic class type like integer and send the array
2. try to send one MyObject instead of an array

After that you can see where is the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're writing and reading your objects back in the **same order every time**. In my case I realized I was writing to the file with optional parameters like this:

```
if(cacheAllItems) { // <-- BREAKS READING FILE WHEN FALSE
   objectOutputStream.writeObject(itemsList);
   objectOutputStream.writeObject(itemNamesList);
}
objectOutputStream.writeObject(currentItem);
```

Then I was attempting to read the file with:

```
itemsList = (ArrayList<Item>) objectInputStream.readObject(); // MIGHT NOT EXIST
itemNames = (ArrayList<String>) objectInputStream.readObject(); // MIGHT NOT EXIST
currentItem = (Item) objectInputStream.readObject();
```

So if I had last run my `cacheItems()` function with the `cacheAllItems` = true, everything worked fine, but if it had last run just saving `currentItem`, the `readObject()` attempted to read the one object as the list that should come first.